# not able to import createSelector from @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am getting an error Module '".../node_modules/@ngrx/store/index"' has no exported member 'createSelector' while importing it from @ngrx/store.

I am using @ngrx/store@2.2.3

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not there. createSelector functionality was added in NgRx version 4 or above.